# How can I turn my keyboard backlight on and off?

Tags: windows-7, backlight

I just got my brand new Toshiba Laptop Satelite L675. In the brochure it is said that the Keyboard has a back light.

How do I turn it on, and off when I don't need it?

Answer (score 2):

It is `Fn + F6` and `Fn + F7`. At least that is what I can see from this picture:

[image]

It might be though that the Fn key is pressed by default, in which case it will be just F6 and F7.